# Disable default highlight on hover in Apache Echarts

Tags: hover, echarts, recharts

Echart version update highlight the line series on hover by default, is there any workaround or a fix for this issue? To keep it more static and not highlight the lineseries data?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think echarts support this yet, a good option is to set the emphasis color and the normal color to the same value:

```
itemStyle: {
  normal: { color: '#aColor' },
  emphasis: { color: '#aColor'}
}
```